# Webpack Dev Server with react & SSR

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to build a dev server with `webpack-dev-server` using our own SSR architecture. This means our bundle compiles the react, and the server uses `React.RenderToStaticMarkup` to generate the HTML string. This is my webpack-dev-server config:

```
      {
        port: 5001,
        open: true,
        static: `${config.distDir}`,
        client: {
          overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true,
          },
          progress: true,
        },
        devMiddleware: {
          writeToDisk: true,
        },
```

Both the `overlay` and the `progress` properties don't seem to work at all, I do get compilation errors in the terminal, but nothing in the browser.

Since I'm doing dynamic SSR, this means the bundle generates a JS file and the server uses `React.renderToStaticMarkup` for generating the html string.

Can this setup even work with the dev server? What do I need to do to have the overlay and progress show in the browser?